# vba macro: Which table my cursor is in?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Writing a macro I found out that I need to skip the table contents and place my cursor right after that, for this I am using a code as

```
     Selection.Tables(cnt).Select
     Selection.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd
```

Here, cnt is a counter value which increases each time a table is found, but if run the macro in selective pages then how will i know the number of nth table inside which my cursor is.

Comment: Please explain the down vote.If u think the question was irrelevant than why didnt i get an answer in the first few minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Important! This solution allows you to find the number of currently selected table within document.**

Add this function to any your Module:

```
Function WhichTableNo(RNG As Range)

If RNG.Tables.Count > 0 Then
    Dim DOC As Document
    Set DOC = RNG.Parent

    Dim rngTMP As Range
    Set rngTMP = DOC.Range(0, RNG.Tables(1).Range.End)

    WhichTableNo = rngTMP.Tables.Count
Else
    WhichTableNo = "Not in the table"
End If
End Function
```

and to check the table number you could call it this way:

```
debug.Print WhichTableNo(Selection.Range)
```

As a result you get number of table you are currently in.

Answer (score 4):

The table in which your cursor is is always `Selection.Tables(1)`.

```
If Selection.Tables.Count > 0 Then
  Dim r As Range
  Set r = Selection.Tables(1).Range
  r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd

  r.Select
End If
```

In case of nested tables, you might want to also check `Selection.Tables.NestingLevel`. The following will exit any number of nested tables, placing the cursor after the outermost table:

```
If Selection.Tables.Count > 0 Then
  Dim r As Range, i As Long

  Set r = Selection.Range

  For i = 1 To r.Tables.NestingLevel
    Set r = r.Tables(1).Range
    r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Next

  r.Select
End If
```