# VBA - Search a word document for a table containing a specific string and return the table number

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to search a word document for a table containing a specific string, and then return the table number. I then use the table number later on to extract a load of relevant information and put it into excel. The issue I have is returning the table number.

I've got the following code for searching the string which seems to work as it goes into the if statement. However I've got myself totally confused as this doesn't return the correct table number, and seems to get stuck in the if statement as well to boot. Any advice appreciated.

```
With .Range
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "search string"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute
        End With
        
    Do While .Find.Found
        TableNo = .Tables.Count
        Stop
    Loop
    
    End With
```

Comment: Where is the IF statement?  Also, you're returning the count of tables, not the table number  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cell.parent

Comment: Tables do not have an index property.  Thus your code would be better if you iterated through the list of tables using a conventional for loop (for myTableCount = 1 to ActiveDOcument.tables.count) and then you can smplify your search using instr(activedocument.tables.item(myTableCount).range.text, "search string") >0.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647397/vba-macro-which-table-my-cursor-is-in

Comment: Nathan_Sav - I meant the Do While loop apologies - Yes realise that's what I'm returning I should have made that clear, what I want is to return the table number. Freeflow - I see so I work through the tables until I find the one that matches my string, and then do my copying within the loop statement rather than trying to find the index and doing it outside. Thanks I'll try this tomorrow.

Comment: Worked thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document, wdRng As Word.Range
Set wdDoc = Word.ActiveDocument
With wdDoc
    Set wdRng = .Range(0, 0)
    With .Range
        With .Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "search string"
            .Forward = True
            .Format = False
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .MatchWildcards = True
        End With
        Do While .Find.Execute
            If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
                wdRng.End = .End
                TableNo = wdRng.Tables.Count
                MsgBox TableNo
            End If
            .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End With
```

or, even simpler:

```
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document, t As Long
Set wdDoc = Word.ActiveDocument
With wdDoc
  For t = 1 To .Tables.Count
    With .Tables(t).Range.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = "search string"
      .Forward = True
      .Format = False
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .MatchWildcards = True
      .Execute
      If .Found = True Then MsgBox t
    End With
  Next
End With
```